# How to compare two dates from input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, date

there are two inputs

```
From:   <input id="from" type="date" placeholder="dd/mm/yy"><br>
To:   <input id="to" type="date" placeholder="dd/mm/yy">
```

I wanna compare these two inputs so as to ensure that the check out date is no earlier than the check in date. But how to compare? thx

Comment: The html5 date input should and shall always be formatted like `yyyy-MM-dd` If you try to set a value that input value that has the format `dd/mm/yy` then you would get a invalid value. Just thinking that you should change your placeholder...

Comment: @Endless—not all implementations support date inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would do it

HTML

```
<script>
    function compareDates() {
        //Get the text in the elements
        var from = document.getElementById('from').textContent;
        var to = document.getElementById('to').textContent;

        //Generate an array where the first element is the year, second is month and third is day
        var splitFrom = from.split('/');
        var splitTo = to.split('/');

        //Create a date object from the arrays
        var fromDate = Date.parse(splitFrom[0], splitFrom[1] - 1, splitFrom[2]);
        var toDate = Date.parse(splitTo[0], splitTo[1] - 1, splitTo[2]);

        //Return the result of the comparison
        return fromDate < toDate;
    }
</script>

<input id="from" type="date" placeholder="dd/mm/yy"><br>
<input id="to" type="date" placeholder="dd/mm/yy">
<button onclick="compareDates()">Compare</button>
```

Let me know how you get on.

Comment: There are some errors here: *Date.parse* is not a constructor, and only takes one argument, `new Date.parse(...)` should be `new Date(…)`. Also, months are zero indexed so `new Date(splitFrom[0], splitFrom[1] - 1, splitFrom[2])`. An answer should explain the issue and how to fix it, not just post code.

Answer (score 3):

For Browsers which support the "date" input, the input value is a DOMString representing a date in YYYY-MM-DD format, or empty.
So (if the input values are not empty) you can just compare the two strings:

```
const FROM = document.getElementById("from").value;
const TO = document.getElementById("to").value;
return FROM < TO;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use valueAsDate and then use the comparator:

```
 input1 = document.getElementById('from');
 input2 = document.getElementById('to');

 date1 = input1.valueAsDate;
 date2 = input2.valueAsDate;
 console.log(date1 < date2 ? 'valid' : 'invalid');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your date format to be dd/mm/yy, you can use the following function to convert the string to date :

```
function compareDate(str){
 // str format should be dd/mm/yyyy. Separator can be anything e.g. / or -. It wont effect
 var dt   = parseInt(str.substring(0,2));
 var mon  = parseInt(str.substring(3,5));
 var yr   = parseInt(str.substring(6,10));
 var date = new Date(yr, mon-1, dt);
 return date;
}
```

Then simply get the values from inputs and compare them as date

```
var input1 = compareDate(document.getElementById('from').value);
var input2 = compareDate(document.getElementById('to').value);
```

The Date object will do what you want - construct one for each date, then compare them using the >, <, <= or >=.

Comment: Maybe try using `input.valueAsDate`?

Comment: @Endless—browser support for *valueAsDate* is…?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of your inputs by using javascript:

```
var fromValue = document.getElementById('from').value;
var toValue = document.getElementById('to').value;
```

then use the javascript date object to convert them to dates:

```
var fromDate = new Date(fromValue);
var toDate = new Date(toValue);
```

and remove time since midnight:

```
fromDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
toDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
```

then compare `fromDate` to `toDate`:

```
if (fromDate === toDate) { ... }
```

Comment: Maybe try using `input.valueAsDate`?

Comment: Of course, good luck.  Don't forget to include @Endless suggestion if you'd like to remove a couple lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `diff` method in `Moment.js`

```
var today = new Date();
var diff = moment().diff(today, 'days');
console.log(diff); // 0
```

More: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/